# Are mango seeds edible?

Tags: health, fruits, seeds

Is it safe to blend in a mango pit for the fruit juice? Is it healthy or not? Some seeds can be mildly toxic, therefore I'm asking about the edibility of mango seeds.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes!  You're completely safe to blend in the pit in terms of healthiness.  However, I make no guarantee your blender won't go kaboom. [More information regarding the seeds.](https://www.reference.com/food/mango-seeds-poisonous-cd784a19d3204e45)

Do note that other components of the mango plant can be toxic:

Mango stems, skin, and leaves can cause irritation in people who are sensitive to urushiol, the oil that causes a rash in poison oak and ivy. [(source)](http://web.extension.illinois.edu/cfiv/homeowners/120726.html)

Consuming urushiol, if you are sensitive, can lead to a fatal reaction in your throat or stomach. If either part gets irritated and swells, you could not be able to breathe or eat anything. [(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urushiol-induced_contact_dermatitis#Cause)

Comment: "I make no guarantee your blender won't go kaboom" Important disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is safe to eat the mango seed. Often it is boiled, dried, fried and then used as a breath freshener in India. Some people make it into a powder and mix with flour when making chapati. You can also make a butter from the seed and use it for dandruff and other skin issues.

Note: the seed must be shelled. Split the hull and you will find a white or white and green or white and brown seed inside. You will need to boil it and dry it and then pulverize it. It's safe to eat raw but terribly bitter and gives really bad cottonmouth. It also should only be consumed in moderate amounts, not in large amounts!